# Meaning of "Pushing a lower discount worked"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

“Everyone was selling [their games] to distributors at a 55 percent discount. I said, “We’re going to go to some of these distributors, and we’re going to offer them 52 percent.”
Valentine said, “Who the hell are you people to think that you can just rewrite any of the rules of the industry? What makes you think you can get away with that?”
I said, “We really don’t have any choice. Either we’re going to pull this off or we’re not going make it.”

"**Pushing a lower discount worked.**”
Don pounded his fist on the table at our next board meeting and said “You people have to continue to challenge convention.”

What is the meaning of the bolded  sentence of this paragraph? I thought it means a more amount of discount , but with this 'lower' word, I'm confused

Comment: Please provide us with some more context and proof of your own research. Also please explain what part of the sentence it is exactly that you do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the world of sales and marketing "pushing" regards the acceptance of the lower discount by the distributor.

The company/manufacturer pushes the lower discount so they could get higher profits from the sales, essentially forcing the distributor to agree to set a higher price on the item on the shelf.

Thanks @VictorBazarov

Comment: Actually here "pushing" concerns the acceptance of the lower discount by the distributor, and has little to do with getting somebody to buy the product.  The company (manufacturer) pushes the lower discount so they could get higher profits from the sales, essentially forcing the distributor to agree to set a higher price on the item on the shelf.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Shouldn't you add that as an answer instead?

Comment: ... Or you could edit yours and take credit. :-)